# Use both Xampp and Docker in Windows 10

Tags: docker, xampp, localhost

I've Xampp installed and running on my Windows 10 (my localhost), also installed Desktop Docker and execute a container that have own web server and created a host name to point that Docker container.
That host name is also added to `host` file in `system32\drivers\etc` Windows directory.

Docker: https://github.com/frappe/erpnext (Installed by https://github.com/frappe/bench)

Now I have to stop Xampp for accessing that hostname and read from docker container, otherwise apache from Xampp will handle it and open `localhost/` directory listing.

So how can I have both Xampp and Docker container running all times and ignore/disable that spesific host name in Xampp apache and open/handle it by Docker container.